# Setting the choice field of one variable according to the value of another variable in the same form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to plot graphs based on the values of the form variables in my django template.
I have 4 variables (ChoiceFields) in my form
I want my second choice field to change the choices with respect to the value of first variable
Eg. is var1='age' var2_options=['M','F']
     if it is var1='Education', var2_options=['Bachelors','Masters','High School']

here's my code:

views.py-

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
template_name='charts.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = HomeForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
def post(self,request):
    form=HomeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text_1 = form.cleaned_data['post_1']
        global z
        z=text_1
        text = form.cleaned_data['post']
        global b
        b=text
        text1 = form.cleaned_data['post1']
        global c
        c=text1
        text2 = form.cleaned_data['post2']
        global d
        d=text2
    args = {'form':form, 'text_1':text_1,'text':text, 'text1':text1, 'text2':text2}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

charts.html (template)

```
<form method="POST">
            {%csrf_token%}
            {{form.as_ul}}
            <button type="submit">get</button>
            {{form.as_ul}}
            <button type="submit">PLOT GRAPH</button>
        </form>
```

forms.py

```
class HomeForm(forms.Form):

post_1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((None,None),('लिंग :','sex :'),('शिक्षण:','education:'),('जात :','caste :'),('व्यवसाय :','occupation :'))) 
post = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((None,None),('लिंग :','लिंग :'),('शिक्षण:','शिक्षण:'),('जात :','जात :'),('व्यवसाय :','व्यवसाय :'))) 
post1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((None,None),('लिंग :','लिंग :'),('शिक्षण:','शिक्षण:'),('जात :','जात :'),('व्यवसाय :','व्यवसाय :'))) 
post2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((None,None),('bar','bar'),('horizontalBar','horizontalBar'),('line','line')))
```

I have arrays of choices ready for each variable 
How can I pass one variable and then assign the choice field of next variable according to it?

Answer (score 0):

Follow vitors explanations here

[How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)